# Postgres FDW Connection Linux

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw

I am actively working with fdw under windows and Linux.

Under windows opened fdw connections on the other side are closed immediately if the main (and reading/writing) connection under windows is closed.

But under Linux opened fdw connections on partner stay active and open even if the initiating connection is closed.

E.g.
Server 1 (Windows)
Server 2 (Linux)

Server 1 makes a connection to his own local database. Within this connection, he writes/read a table which is a table on Server 2 and is represented locally by the fdw. On Server 2 the postgres_fdw connection to server 1 is visible. If server 1 closes the connection to his local database I can see that the postgres_fdw connection on Server 2 is already closed, which is perfect.

The other way round if I do this from Linux the postgres_fdw connection on Server 1 is still existing event if the local connection on Server 2 is closed.

Is there any possibility to config this?

Answer (score 0):

What version of postgres are you running?

Are you using a Web / application server?

There may be a scenario such as nginx with keepalive connections where the HTTP sessions  and the number of Postgres sessions grows beyond your PG connection limit